# How to validate datetime format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ" in Symfony 2 form

Tags: php, symfony, date, datetime, symfony-forms

One of you know how to validate a datetime with "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ" (ISO 8601) format in Symfony form ?

My formType:

```
    /**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('Name', 'text')

        ->add('Summary', 'textarea')

        ->add('Objective', 'text')

        ->add('Target_Date', 'date', array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'input' => 'datetime',
            'format' => 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ',
            ))

        ->add('Type', 'text')

        ->add('Members', 'text', array('mapped'=>false));
    }
```

POST from AngluarJS to Symfony api

Target_Date: "2015-04-01T22:00:48.131Z"

But I get : Target_Date: this value is not valide.

Thanks !

Comment: Can we have the constraints applied to this field in your entity?

Comment: According to the ICU 54.1 format docs,  believe you need `.SSS` for fractional seconds; and you may also need to enclose `T` in quotes: `'T'`

Comment: The bundled symfony datetime validator don't support your date pattern. See [DateTimeValidator](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/43c05650c664f6b164a332237b8da485acb1a995/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/DateTimeValidator.php#L25) or [DateValidator](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/43c05650c664f6b164a332237b8da485acb1a995/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/DateValidator.php#L26). So you can write your custom implemented your own regex pattern or directly the [RegEx](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html). Hope this help

Comment: @D4V1D: My Constraints :   `/**
  * @var DateTime
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="Target_Date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
  * @Assert\NotBlank()
  * @Assert\DateTime()
  */
 private $Target_Date;`

Comment: MarkBaker I will try !  Matteo: Good idea !   Thanks for you feedback !

Comment: Let we know what solution will work for you! good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I just changed 'date' to 'datetime' and 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ' to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS". See below:

```
    /**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('Name', 'text')

        ->add('Summary', 'textarea')

        ->add('Objective', 'text')

        ->add('Target_Date', 'datetime', array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'input' => 'datetime',
            'format' => "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS",
            ))

        ->add('Type', 'text')

        ->add('Members', 'text', array('mapped'=>false));
    }
```

Thanks everyone for your help !!